# using id="submit" twice on one page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am creating a login/register part to a site. And the login and register forms are on page.

Like:

```
<form name="loginform" style="text-align:center;" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="index.php">
                <div class="row">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email Address" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <button id="submit" type="submit" class="button large arrow-type-2 dark">Log Me In</button>
                </div>
            </form>


<form name="registerform" style="text-align:center;" method="post" onsubmit="return validatethisForm();" action="index.php">
                    <div class="row">
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email Address"/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password"/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <button id="submit" type="submit" class="button large arrow-type-2 dark">Create Free Account</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

My Js Validation is: ( needs work )

```
function validateForm()
        {
        var x=document.forms["loginform"]["email"].value;
        var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
          {
          alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
          return false;
          }
         var x=document.forms["loginform"]["password"].value;
            if (x==null || x=="")
              {
              alert("Please enter a Password");
              return false;
              }
        }
        function validatethisForm()
        {
        var x=document.forms["registerform"]["email2"].value;
        var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
          {
          alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
          return false;
          }
         var x=document.forms["registerform"]["password2"].value;
            if (x==null || x=="")
              {
              alert("Please enter a Password");
              return false;
              }
        }
```

The issue I have is page validation, everything works perfect. But because I have duplicate submit id's , I need to clean this up.

Can you offer suggestions on improving my code above ?

/////////////////////////////////////////

Using: code below for cross browser placeholder

```
$('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
var input = $(this);
 if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
   input.val('');
   input.removeClass('placeholder');
  }
  }).blur(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.addClass('placeholder');
    input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
   }
  }).blur().parents('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
   var input = $(this);
   if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
     input.val('');
    }
   })
   });
```

Comment: Why do you need that ID ? It's not necessary, functionally speaking. you can just remove it AFAIK.

Comment: I don't really see jQuery in this.

Comment: the id have to be unique on a page. Not for nothing the the name is ``id`` (identification)

Comment: I know they haveto be unique,thats why i am asking. Is it simpky a case i can omit them? Or rename class=submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified your HTML code to the following:

```
<form name="loginForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="index.php">
    <label>Email Address: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email Address"/></label>
    <label>Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/></label>
    <button type="submit" class="button large arrow-type-2 dark">Log In</button>
</form>


<form name="registerForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validatethisForm();"
      action="index.php">
    <label>Email Address: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email Address"/></label>
    <label>Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/></label>
    <button type="submit" class="button large arrow-type-2 dark">Create Free Account</button>
</form>
```

### Points

- Always include a label. Not all browsers support HTML5 placeholders.
- All IDs here are reluctant. Forms can be accessed by

  ```
  var loginForm = document.forms.loginForm; //By name
  ```

  and form elements by

  ```
  loginForm.email; //Also by name
  ```
- No need for `div`s and `br`s to manage the line breaks. Use the labels themselves. Add `display: block;` as necessary.
- Don't use inline style attribute. Use a CSS `<style>` element or an external stylesheet.
- There's no AutoComplete on password fields.
- Use HTML5's new form input types. `type="email"` will have the browser natively validate the field and notify the user if the email is not valid.
- Keep it simple. No need for bloating.

Comment: The forms actually launch within Modal windows. I tried Overlabel, but it messed stuff up. I was gonna utilise jquery placeholder plugin.

Comment: Thankyou for heads up on password field, appreciate your reply.

Comment: I was actually toying with using "shake" instead of Alert, as we are using modals. Will look into that too. Voted your answer , regards

Comment: Labels are still important part of accessibility. My suggestion is to have an explicit label (`<label for="email">Email:</label><input id="email">`) and simply hide the label with `height: 0;` or `visibility: hidden;`. To allow screen readers to see it.

Comment: Thats a good idea, will do that @truth. Updated question with placeholder code. Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Since both functions do the same thing, just make one function and bind it to both forms 'onsubmit' event.

You taggued is as jquery ,so, jquery-style, using Mike Alsup's [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

```
function validate(formData, jqForm, options) { 
    // formData is an array of objects representing the name and value of each field 
    // that will be sent to the server;  it takes the following form: 
    // 
    // [ 
    //     { name:  username, value: valueOfUsernameInput }, 
    //     { name:  password, value: valueOfPasswordInput } 
    // ] 
    // 
    // To validate, we can examine the contents of this array to see if the 
    // username and password fields have values.  If either value evaluates 
    // to false then we return false from this method. 

    for (var i=0; i < formData.length; i++) { 
        if (!formData[i].value) { 
            alert('Please enter a value for both Username and Password'); 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 
    alert('Both fields contain values.'); 
}
$('form').ajaxForm( { beforeSubmit: validate } );
```

This example and more info [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#validation).